# How can I Loop copy/paste across worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a loop which will go through a workbook and do the following:
1.Select a worksheet
2.Copy a selection of cells on selected worksheet
3.Return to a Master or "home" sheet
4.Paste the copied values in the next empty row of this master sheet
5.Go to the next worksheet and start the process again.

I've tried to get this rolling with the below code, but I'm afraid I'm still new to VBA, looping, and dynamic range selection.

```
Sub Create_One_Table()

Dim wrksht As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, rng

For Each wrksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    With wrksht

            Range("BB2").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("05").Select
            Range("BB17").Select
           Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
            Sheets("05").Paste
    End With

Next wrksht

End Sub
```

My question is how can I change the above code to do the actions I specified at first? The above code as is copies and pastes only portions of what I need it to (meaning it's incomplete).Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've spent a lot of time fumbling through this so far. Thanks,

Comment: What is your question? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Updated post to (hopefully) be more clear

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the basics there.  I have a few pointers:

1. When using `with` blocks, access properties of the `with` object by starting them with a `.`.  I've updated the `Range` calls below to `.Range` to demonstrate.  As it is the first three usages of `Range` in your with block are accessing whatever sheet is selected, since you also never select each `wrksht` in the loop.
2. There is no need to use `.select` to hold your place.  You can refer to the `Range(ref)` directly, and you can chain `.end` together also.  This makes execution much faster and also prevents the need to switch to the sheet you are getting data from.  See how I copied the range with one command and no selections.
3. You can refer to sheets labels such as `Sheets("Master")`.  I find this easier than their numbers.

I've incorporated this into the below code.  It's not actually tested because I don't know your layout, but I hope it helps.

```
Sub Create_One_Table()
Dim wrksht As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, rng
'Make sure "Master" is selected because this is the only one you need to select cells on (to paste)
Sheets("Master").Select
For Each wrksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With wrksht
            .Range(.Range("BB2"), .Range("BB2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    End With
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next wrksht
End Sub
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I seem to be having an error though where it says "ActiveSheet.Paste". It says "Paste method of Worksheet class failed. I'm not too sure what that means,